# Move .tar from /tmp to other specified location

Tags: python

My script will generate a random `.tar` file and saves the file in tmp folder, but I want to get that generated `.tar` file each time from the tmp folder and save it on to Desktop or a desired location.

**I tried:**

```
for i in xrange(n):
        print "---------------"
        print " **** Creating Your Licene File **** "
        os.system("./createDevlicense.sh -f {}  -d {}  -a {} -t {} -w {} -g {}". format(flavour,days,apid,type,warning,grace))
```

Above `./createDevlicese.sh` is a bash script which I'm using in my py script. This will generate a `.tar` file and save it in `/tmp` folder, 
but I want to get that generated `.tar` file each time from tmp folder and save it on Desktop or desired location.

Comment: how can i do that. how can i get that file from /tmp folder and save it in different path? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way but the first thing that came to mind was to create a watchdog to watch the folder in which the file is created and then use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) for moving the file to desired location.

You can try this:

```
import time
import shutil
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Watcher:

    def __init__(self):

        self.directory = 'directory/to/watch'
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.directory, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()

        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
        print("Watchdog error!")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def process(self, event):

        if event.event_type == 'created':
            shutil.move(event.src_path, 'desired/directory/to/save/')


    def on_created(self, event):

        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Note that this is python3. You can also run this in a thread.

Comment: can i use something like this                                                  
     os.system("cp -r /tmp/can_license_*****.tar    /User/foo/Desktop")         or ask the user for path where to save

Comment: Under the `if event.event_type == 'created'` you can put whatever method you want. I would suggest to create a function outside this class which you call every time a file is created. In the function you can use raw_input (python2) or input (python3) for user specific path together with the os.system command. Note that `event.src_path`returns the full path the file is created including the file name.